# Interactive update dropdown list

Tags: javascript, react-native, logic, dataflow

I would like to implement those drop-downs where data is updated as you select previous inputs, for example you select `Sony` as a 'brand' and then you got all `Sony` TV models.. then all variations of that model, I have all the data on array but initially it's on airtable (csv like) ) not sure how to handle it, should I save parameters and work the way down or there's some library that makes this task easier? Thanks, any suggestion appreciated

[image: e]

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful if you provide what your current attempt is so that we can tell what you're actually trying to accomplish that.

Here is a very basic example of *Cascading Dropdowns* using JS

```js
const data = [
  { brand: 'Brand A', models: [ 'model a1', 'model a2', 'model a3' ] },
  { brand: 'Brand B', models: [ 'model b1', 'model b2', 'model b3' ] },
  { brand: 'Brand C', models: [ 'model c1', 'model c2', 'model c3' ] },
  { brand: 'Brand D', models: [ 'model d1', 'model d2', 'model d3' ] },
];

const brands = document.getElementById('brands');
const models = document.getElementById('models');

// Populate the Brands dropdown from the data set
data.forEach( d => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = d.brand;
  option.innerText = d.brand;
  brands.append(option);
});

// Anytime the Brand changes, repopulate the models
// dropdown based off the selected brand
brands.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  const brand = data.find( d => d.brand === val);
  models.innerHTML = '';
  brand.models.forEach( m => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = m;
    option.innerText = m;
    models.append(option);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Brand</label>
  <select id="brands">
    <option>Select</option>
    <!-- options are dynamic -->
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Model</label>
  <select id="models">
    <!-- options are dynamic -->
  </select>
</div>
```